# Regular expression to extract string before and the string after the third hyphen

Tags: regex

Am trying to parse strings similar to these variations:

- "AB-19-027654-A-1"
- "AB-19-027654-A-1-2"
- "ABC-19-027654-A-1"
- "ABC-19-027654-A-1-2"

Looking for a way to use regular expression to have the above strings split at the **third hyphen** into two strings.

- "AB-19-027654-A-1"  split into  "AB-19-027654" and "A-1"
- "AB-19-027654-A-1-2" split into  "AB-19-027654" and "A-1-2"
- "ABC-19-027654-A-1" split into  "ABC-19-027654" and "A-1"
- "ABC-19-027654-A-1-2"  split into   "ABC-19-027654" and "A-1-2"

Have tried something like this **^(?'STRING1'.+[\d-}])-(?'STRING2'.*)-??$**
but it does work for all the combinations listed.

The only consistency I can find in the original strings is that there is always at least three hyphens and the two strings I need are before and after that third hyphen accordingly.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just `^([^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*)-(.*)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex with two capture groups:

```
/^((?:[^-]+-?){3})-(.*)$/
```

Explanation:

- `^` - start of string
- `(` - start capture group 1

  - `(?:[^-]+-?){3}` - non-capturing group of characters other than `-` followed by optional `-`, repeated 3 times
- `)` - end capture group 1
- `-` - literal `-`
- `(.*)` - capture group 2: everything to end of string
- `$` - end of string

Comment: (This is just an edge case, but if the data is `ABC-19-027654--A-1-2` it would have the last `-` in the first group as it is optional. I think unrolling it could prevent it `^([^-]+(?:-[^-]+){2})-+(.*)$` https://regex101.com/r/lotNLV/1)